# C# axmediaplayer control

Tags: c#, .net

I am implementing the AXMEDIAPLAYER control in a .Net 4 C# application and have been trying to code FF/RW functions.  This is to play .WMA files and only the scan forward native function is available so I was trying to code them both programmatically by using a timer and stepping the .currentposition property.  The problem I have is that when the audio file is playing, after I step the .currentposition property, it is decreasing by a varying amount...between 1 and 1.5.  Has anybody had this occur, or can you point me to what might be causing the problem.  Thank you.

```
axMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition++;
tbPosition.Value++;
lblCurrentPosition.Text = axMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPositionString;
```

...that is the code I am using in the timer event to advance the currentposition and relevant trackbar.

EDIT!!! --- THe issue appears to be related to Variable vs Constant bit rate...VBR works whereas CBR doesn't.

Comment: Attach relevant parts of your solution in your question.

Comment: ...updated with code segment from the Timer event...when paused it advances fine, when playing it falls backwards.  I've also tested play/pause and found unless I catch it it will bounce backwards as well.